# Getting button click event for button inside jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

When i click the anchor tag,the fancybox gets popup.It contains a textbox and a button.I need to get the click event of button and the text in the textbox.
My code is

```
<a href="#test" class="fancybox">Open</a>
    <div id="test" style="display:none;width:300px;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="100px" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Ok" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
```

Comment: the click event is, well, a `click` ... did you rather mean the ID, the event target or else?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the asp.net button control's **OnClientClick** property and assign a javascript function.

```
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="click()" />
```

Then define a javascript function

```
  function click()
  {
    //do something
  }
```

more details here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.